# I can't understand the structure declaration in c++

Tags: c++, c, class, struct, structure

In C, we have to use a struct prefix whenever we want to declare or define a structure. However, things have been changed once the structure became a kind of a class in c++. We no longer need to use a `struct` prefix when we declare a structure. In this vein, I guess the structure tag in `C` became a name of a type in `C++`.

However, it does not mean that we can't use a `struct` prefix. We still can use a `struct` prefix. For example, Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of c++, introduces an example of declaring a structure both with and without a `struct` prefix, which makes me puzzled.

Below are structure definitions which try to make a structure with template argument T. These compile fine with no error.

```
template<class T> struct linked_list {
    T element;
    linked_list<T> *next;
};
template<class T> struct linked_list {
    T element;
    struct linked_list<T> *next;
};
```

Now, below are function declarations whose return type and argument type are structures. Even though these are not that different from the above, the first one from below two function declarations, the one with a struct prefix, gives me an error with Visual Studio c++ 2012

```
template<class T> struct linked_list<T> *add_list(T element, struct linked_list<T> *tail);
template<class T> linked_list<T> *add_list(T element, linked_list<T> *tail);
```

I really don't understand how things work. I don't understand the differences between these declarations. Could anyone give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: Are you asking why you can omit the `struct` keyword in C++? [Why does C need “struct” keyword and not C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422775/why-does-c-need-struct-keyword-and-not-c)

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Not all C++ comply to the standards.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thank you. However, i still have a question. The link that you gave me said if there is no ambiguity the c++ 'allows' the omission of the struct keyword. It means we can still use the struct keyword. It then follows that there is an ambiguity in my second codes because it gives me an error. However, I don't see any ambiguity. What's wrong?

Comment: @Anycorn I'm using the visual studio c++ 2012.

Comment: With g++, both lines compile.

Comment: @Anycorn Wow. Thank you for your help. I have an another question. The reason why a structure can have a template argument is because a structure is a kind of a class? I remember Bjarne Stroustrup saying that only a class and a function can have a template argument.

Comment: @bis0317: In C++ the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that `struct` members are public by default and `class` members are private by default.  Other than the default member visibility, there is _no differences whatsoever_

Comment: Also "As you already know, a structure is a class whose members are all public, which makes it possible that we no longer need to use a struct prefix when we declare a structure."  Those two things are 100% completely unrelated, not cause and effect.

Comment: I've confirmed that neither MSVC '08 nor MSVC '12 will compile his code.

Comment: It can be compiled now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than in C, in C++ the `struct` (and `class`) keyword may be omitted, if there is no ambuiguity. *If* there is ambiguity, you still have to use the `struct` keyword. A notorious example is POSIX' `stat`: there is a `struct stat` and a function `stat`. Here you always have to use `struct stat` to refer to the type.

Answer (score -1):

You do seem to understand pretty well as you explain it yourself.  In C++ the keyword struct is the same as the keyword class but with a default of public rather than private members. 
So having declared a class using the struct keyword you do not then use it again when referring to that class. You seem to be trying use struct as it would be used in C in the first example. This is just different for C++.

Comment: So, you're basically summed up his question.

Comment: However, It is possible that we use a struct prefix even after the definition of a structure. We can see this in my first code. It's so complicated. :-(

Comment: It's not really complicated it is just that C++ is a different language to C. The keyword struct means something different.  Objective-C is an extension of C so all C remains valid, but Stroustrup decided not to maintain such downward compatibility when designing C++.

Comment: @DavidElliman: I just reread that and realized that though you're 100% correct, the backwards compatability doesn't explain anything about this question.  C++ can compile most C code, and Objective-C can compile all C code.  All three compile `struct linked_list<T>`.