# Undeclared identifier linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, syntax-error, undeclared-identifier

I'm a total noob to C, trying to make a functional linked list. with the listInsert function sorting the list alphabetically.
But there's a problem, i get a C2059 Syntax error and C2065 error: 'listEntry' : undeclared identifier on the following line in listInsert function:

```
newNode = (listEntry *)malloc(sizeof(listEntry));
```

Like i said i'm a complete noob, but i dont see any missing brackets anywhere, and im pretty sure that is the line that defines the newNode?
All help will be appreciated, thankyou.

Also, here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL    1

char *phonetic[] = { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot",
                     "golf", "hotel", "india", "juliet", "kilo", "lima", "mike",
                     "november", "oscar", "papa", "quebec", "romeo", "sierra",
                     "tango", "uniform", "victor", "whisky", "xray", "yankee", 
                     "zulu" };

unsigned char indexes[] = { 1, 14, 17, 3, 22, 0, 5, 18, 24, 11, 4, 6, 13, 21,
                            2, 12, 25, 19, 10, 16, 7, 9, 23, 15, 20, 8 };                       

// represents an entry in the linked-list
struct listEntry
{
  char *data_p;               // pointer to the entry's string
  struct listEntry *prev_p;   // pointer to previous entry in the linked-list  
  struct listEntry *next_p;   // pointer to next entry in the linked-list
};

// represents the linked-list
struct list
{
  int entryCount;             // number of entries present in the linked-list
  struct listEntry *head_p;   // pointer to the first entry in the list  
  struct listEntry *tail_p;   // pointer to the last entry in the list
};

// Dynamically allocate & initialise an empty linked list
int listCreate(struct list** list_p2)
{
  // allocate struct list from heap 
  *list_p2 = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof(**list_p2));

  if (*list_p2 != NULL)
  {
    // zero-initialize the list structure 
    memset(*list_p2, 0, sizeof(**list_p2));
    return SUCCESS;    
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Free all entries in the linked-list and the list structure
int listDestroy(struct list *list_p)
{
  if (list_p != NULL)
  {
    struct listEntry *entry_p = list_p->head_p;

    while (entry_p != NULL)
    {
      struct listEntry *next_p = entry_p->next_p;
      // free the current entry
      free(entry_p);
      // move to the next entry
      entry_p = next_p;
    }

    // free list structure
    free(list_p);
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Traverse the linked-list from head to tail printing out
// the string data from each list entry
int listPrintForward(struct list *list_p)
{ 
  if (list_p)
  {    
    struct listEntry *entry_p = list_p->head_p;
    int count = 0;

    printf("FORWARD: %d entries\n", list_p->entryCount);
    while (entry_p != NULL)
    {
      if ((count > 0) && (count % 5 == 0))
      {
        printf("%s\n", entry_p->data_p);
      }
      else
      {      
        printf("%s ", entry_p->data_p);
      }

      if (entry_p == list_p->tail_p)
        printf("\n");

      entry_p = entry_p->next_p;
      fflush(stdout);
      count++;         
    }

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Traverse the linked-list from tail to head printing out
// the string data from each list entry
int listPrintReverse(struct list *list_p)
{ 
  if (list_p)
  {    
    struct listEntry *entry_p = list_p->tail_p;
    int count = 0;

    printf("REVERSE: %d entries\n", list_p->entryCount);   
    while (entry_p != NULL)
    {
      if ((count > 0) && (count % 5 == 0))
      {
        printf("%s\n", entry_p->data_p);
      }
      else
      {      
        printf("%s ", entry_p->data_p);
      }

      if (entry_p == list_p->head_p)
        printf("\n");

      entry_p = entry_p->prev_p;
      fflush(stdout);
      count++;         
    }

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Insert the given string into the linked-list such that the
// entries in the linked-list are in alphabetical order
void listInsert(struct list *list_p,char *string_p)
{
    struct listEntry *newNode;
    newNode = (listEntry *)malloc(sizeof(listEntry));
  // Please write the listInsert function



    //Special case for the head end.
    if (list_p->head_p == NULL || (list_p->head_p)->data_p >= newNode->data_p)
  {
     newNode->next_p = list_p->head_p;
     list_p->head_p = newNode;
  }
    else
    {
        //Locating the node before which the insertion is to happen.
        struct listEntry* current = list_p->head_p;
        while(current->next_p!= NULL && current->next_p->data_p < newNode->data_p)
        {
            current = current->next_p;
        }
        newNode->next_p = current->next_p;
        current->next_p = newNode;

    }


  //return FAIL;  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct list *list_p = NULL;
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;

  if (listCreate(&list_p) == SUCCESS)
  {
    unsigned int count;

    // insert every word in the phonetic alphabet into the
    // linked-list.
    printf("INSERT:\n");
    for (count = 0; count < sizeof(indexes); count++)
    {
      if ((count > 0) && (count % 5 == 0))
      {
        printf("%s\n", phonetic[indexes[count]]);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%s ", phonetic[indexes[count]]);
      }
      listInsert(list_p, phonetic[indexes[count]]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // print out the list in alphabetical order
    listPrintForward(list_p);
    // print out the list in reverse alphabetical order
    listPrintReverse(list_p); 

    // Destroy the linked list and free all associated memory
    listDestroy(list_p);               
  }

  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that `listEntry` by itself doesn't describe a type. You need to add `struct` keyword beforehand, since you haven't `typedef`'d `listEntry`.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422775/why-does-c-need-struct-keyword-and-not-c).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write

```
newNode = malloc(sizeof newNode);
```

It should compile without problems and is also better because you don't need to modify it if you change the type of newNode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newNode = (struct listEntry *)malloc(sizeof(struct listEntry));
```

Or you can define new type and use it:

```
typedef struct listEntry
{
  char *data_p;               // pointer to the entry's string
  struct listEntry *prev_p;   // pointer to previous entry in the     linked-list
  struct listEntry *next_p;   // pointer to next entry in the linked-list
} t_listEntry;



newNode = (t_listEntry *)malloc(sizeof(t_listEntry));
```