# Correct way of creating structures in c++

Tags: c++, struct

When learning C++, the books always create structs as follows:

```
struct X{
    int a;
};

X y; 
X *yp; // pointer to object of X class
```

But I've seen some C++ code online where people instead use the following syntax:

```
struct X y;
struct X *yp;
```

Why do they add the struct in front and is there any difference between the two methods of creating objects of X class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C need "struct" keyword and not C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422775/why-does-c-need-struct-keyword-and-not-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ (as opposed to C) you can mostly just write `X` when `X` is a struct type. You still need to write `struct X`

- for disambiguation in some rare cases, and
- when `X` has not yet been declared.

Examples of the last point:

- in a `friend` declaration,
- as an id type for a template,
- <del>with the usual PIMPL idiom</del> .

Example of the first point:

```
struct A {};
void A() {}

auto main() -> int
{
    void (*f)() = &A;
    //A x;  // !nyet
    struct A x;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the PIMPL idiom bullet point. Not sure what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

This is a heritage from C. In C, the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
};
```

created a struct, and put its **tag** "`Foo`" in its own 'tag-namespace'
the only way to access it was to do:

```
struct Foo foo;
```

Or, more common:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
Foo foo;
```

However, in C++ the tag is not just placed in a separate tag-namespace, but also
in the enclosing namespace. But for backwards compatibility, it still allows you to 
access it using `struct Name`

There is an additional use of the construct `struct Name`, both in C and C++
and that is a forward declaration:

```
struct Later;
```

`Later` is here an incomplete type, you can use it only for things that does not
need to know its size (such as creating a pointer)