# Struct keyword in function parameters, what is the difference?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I wonder, what is the difference between:

```
struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *next;
};
```

and

```
struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
};
```

Why do we need `struct` keyword in second example?

Also, what is the difference between

```
void Foo(Node* head) 
{
    Node* cur = head;
    //....
}
```

and

```
void Foo(struct Node* head) 
{
    struct Node* cur = head;
    //....
}
```

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422775/why-does-c-need-struct-keyword-and-not-c

Comment: C *or* C++ ? The answer is completely different depending on the language.

Comment: What Quentin said. Remove the C++ or the C tag.

Answer (score 5):

Only the declarations including `struct` are valid in C. There is no difference in C++.

However, you can `typedef` the `struct` in C, so you don’t have to write it every time.

```
typedef struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;  // we have not finished the typedef yet
} SNode;

SNode* cur = head;    // OK to refer the typedef here
```

This syntax is also valid in C++ for compatibility.

Comment: *"There is no difference in C++."* - that's not quite true... with `struct Node* next;` is only searches for a `struct`/`class`/`union` by that name and happily ignores non-`struct`/`class`/`union`s with the same identifier.  For example, if you add an `int Node;` data member to `struct Node;`, it won't conflict with `struct Node* next;` but will conflict with `Node* next;`.  Nobody sane relies on this distinction though - makes for unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Struct node is a new user defined datatype that we create. And unlike classes the new data type using structures is  "struct strct_name" , ie; u need the keyword struct in front of the struct_name. 
For classes u do not need keywords in front of the new data type name.
eg;

```
class abc
{
  abc *next;
};
```

and when u declare variables

```
abc x;
```

instead of struct

```
abc x;
```

in case of structures .
Also understand that by the statement

```
struct node * next;
```

we are trying to create a pointer that points to a variable of type "strcut node", which is called a self referential pointer in this case since it points to the parent structure.