# Is it optional to use struct keyword before declaring a structure object?

Tags: c++, c, struct, elaborated-type-specifier

To declare a class object we need the format

```
classname objectname;
```

Is it the sameway to declare a structure object?

like

```
structname objectname;
```

I found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm) a structure object declared as

```
struct Books Book1;
```

where Books is the structure name and Book1 is its object name. So is there any need  of usinge the keyword `struct` before declaring a structure object?

Comment: If you don't use `typedef` or `struct` the compiler doesn't know that `structname` is a type.

Comment: In C, you either need to use the `struct` keyword, or you need to `typedef` the struct type. In C++, the `struct` keyword is optional.

Comment: `class object` is not a C concept.

Comment: in `struct Books book1;` `Books` is not the "structure name", it is the structure tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to *typedef* them to make objects without *struct* keyword

example:

```
typedef struct Books {
     char Title[40];
     char Auth[50];
     char Subj[100];
     int Book_Id;
} Book;
```

Then you can define an object without the *struct* keyword like:

```
Book thisBook;
```

Comment: You don't need the `Books` tag if you aren't going to self-reference the struct within itself as a pointer type.

Comment: @Qix: Another reason to use the `Books` tag is to allow it to be used from other header files without creating a dependency.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Oh true :)

Answer (score 28):

This is one of the differences between C and C++.

In C++, when you define a class you can use the type name with or without the keyword `class` (or `struct`).

```
// Define a class.
class A { int x; };

// Define a class (yes, a class, in C++ a struct is a kind of class).
struct B { int x; };

// You can use class / struct.
class A a;
struct B b;

// You can leave that out, too.
A a2;
B b2;

// You can define a function with the same name.
void A() { puts("Hello, world."); }

// And still define an object.
class A a3;
```

In C, the situation is different.  Classes do not exist, instead, there are structures.  You can, however, use typedefs.

```
// Define a structure.
struct A { int x; };

// Okay.
struct A a;

// Error!
A a2;

// Make a typedef...
typedef struct A A;

// OK, a typedef exists.
A a3;
```

It is not uncommon to encounter structures with the same names as functions or variables.  For example, the `stat()` function in POSIX takes a `struct stat *` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. One question: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423005/10027592) says that even C++ *requires* the `struct` keyword in your example (`stat()` function in POSIX systems). So, in these kinds of cases where function and structure have the same name, `struct` *must* be used even in C++?

Comment: @starriet: Yes. The difference is that in C++, `struct` may be omitted in other scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. In case of **C** language, you need to explicitly give the type of the variable otherwise the compiler will throw an error: ***'Books' undeclared***.(in the above case)

So you need to use keyword **struct** if you are using **C** language but you can skip this if you are writing this in **C++**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `g++` means you're actually writing C++, not C.

Comment: yes but the compiler-driver decides to which libraries the code will be linked. So I differentiated on the basis of compiler-drivers.

Comment: @RohitTakhar: But if you use `g++` to compile a `.c` file, it will be compiled and linked as C++, you're just writing C++ with a funny extension at that point.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Right. I have edited my post to make it more clear.