# Why am I not getting any output, for my code on insertion in linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion

I am trying to create a singly linked list by inserting nodes at end, and despite having no errors I am unable to print my linked list. Please help me debug my code.

I tried online compiler on codechef and it shows SIGSEGV Runtime error. What is this supposed to mean?

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};

void insert(struct node *root,int data)
{
struct node *temp=new(struct node);

if(root==NULL)
{
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
}

root->next=temp;
temp->data=data;
temp->next=NULL;

}

void print(struct node *root)
{
struct node *temp;
temp=root;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    cout<<temp->data;
            temp=temp->next;

}

}

int main()
{
struct node *root=NULL;
insert(root,1);
    insert(root,2);
insert(root,3);
insert(root,4);
print(root);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Please help me debug my code."_ Nope! Stack Overflow isn't a free online debugging service. There are ways you can help yourself even online, e.g.: https://www.onlinegdb.com/.

Comment: It means you're code invokes undefined behavior. Your `insert` is broken in multiple places.

Comment: "it shows SIGSEGV Runtime error. What is this supposed to mean?" - A segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) means that your program tried to read or write memory outside its allocated address space. This is a fatal error and the kernel (rightly) killed the program for the violation.

Comment: Please don't use `NULL` in new code. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: You may want to spend a bit of time investigating [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)...

Comment: "I am trying to create a singly linked list" - instead of just using [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) - *Why*?

Comment: _"despite having no errors"_ -- Are you sure about this? Being unable to print is an error. A SIGSEGV runtime **error** is an error. Lots of errors. -- Perhaps you meant no compile-time errors? (Not that the lack of compile time errors should ever be taken as evidence that a program will work as intended. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please help me debug my code*.

OK lets try a *dry run*.

Imagine your list is empty and you are inserting your first item. So `root` equals `NULL` and we call `insert`.

1) first thing

```
struct node *temp=new(struct node);
```

You allocate a new node, and set `temp` equal to it, so far so good.

2) next thing

```
if(root==NULL)
```

this is true as explained in the preamble, so we enter the if statement

3) next thing

```
temp->data=data;
temp->next=NULL;
```

these statements in the if body get executed and initialise the newly allocated object. It's not clear why you only want to do this when `root == NULL`, I would think you would want to initialise the newly allocated node always. But anyway, so far no errors.

4) next thing

```
root->next=temp;
```

Now here's the error. Ask yourself, what is the value of `root` at this point? When we started it was `NULL`, has anything changed it since? The answer of course is no, so you are dereferencing a NULL pointer. That explains the error.

You need to be able to look at the code you've written and see it for what it really does. The ability to *dry run* your code like I did above is a very valuable skill to have.

Unfortunately your code really is not very close to being correct. So I think the best thing would be to look at some working code and see how it operates and then start again.

Comment: I didn't see this struct node *temp=new(struct node); it's everywhere

Comment: @Oblivion I was going to comment on the dubious syntax, but I thought it better to concentrate in the main point. For the OP, that line is better written as `node* temp = new node;`

Comment: @john i wanted to create an initial node by using **if(root==NULL)** ; i tried making a head and tail node instead and it works.  if(head == NULL){head = temp; tail =temp; } else {tail->next = temp;tail = tail->next; }   Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @john the OP has used C style. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39838629/10933809